# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^{\ln(2)} \sqrt{(e^x-1)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate the integral $\int_0^{\ln(2)} \sqrt{(e^x-1)}dx$

Why is it wrong to...

$$\int_0^{\ln(2)} \sqrt{(e^x-1)} dx= \int_0^{\ln(2)} (e^x-1)^{1/2} dx= \frac{2}{3}(e^x-1)^{3/2} |_0^{\ln(2)}$$

Comment: Probably not the "why" you are wanting, but the derivative of ${2 \over 3}(e^x - 1)^{3 \over 2}$ is not the expression you originally integrate. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to find the derivative of $e^x -1$ to replace $dx$ in the original integral.

Put $e^x - 1 = u$. Then $e^x = u+1$.

Then $du = e^x\,dx\iff dx = \frac{du}{u+1}$

This gives us $$\int_0^1 \frac{u^{1/2}}{u+1} \,du$$

Comment: You're welcome, AlonAlon!

Answer (score 2):

because $$\frac{d}{dx}(e^x-1)^{3/2}=\frac{3}{2}(e^x-1)^{1/2}e^x$$

also hint; let $y=e^x-1$ to solve it.